# How to tell what files on remote repository changed since last git pull?

Tags: git

I'm trying to push some code using `$git push origin master` but I get the error

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

When I did `$ git fetch origin master` then `$ git diff master origin/master` I got a list of all the files and changes that were different between the two repos.  However I am only interested in the list of files that have changed between the remote repository and the last time I did a `$ git pull origin master` on my local box.

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 8):

`git pull` is the same as `git fetch` followed by `git merge` (or `git rebase`).

`git fetch` shows which refs where updated. It will show something like:

```
a8e5e4e..295bf31  master     -> origin/master
```

This means the last time you fetched master it was at a8e5e4e now it is at 295bf31.
You can see the changed files with something like:

```
git diff --name-status a8e5e4e..295bf31
```

But maybe even more interesting is the output of `gitk master...origin/master` after the fetch. This way you can inspect both the changes on your side and the changes on origin side.

Comment: I found that with --name-status I also needed --name-only to only show the file names and not the differences.

Answer (score 5):

[michas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18297159/1256452) is the right one for the question as asked.

What if you don't have the old ref, i.e., the `a8e5e4e` part of `a8e5e4e..295bf31  master     -> origin/master`?  Probably you don't actually care: as he suggested, looking at `master...origin/master` can be even more interesting.<sup>1</sup>  But, what does this three-dot `...` syntax actually *mean*?

The answer is in the [`git rev-list`](https://www.kernel.org/pub//software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html) documentation:

> Another special notation is `<commit1>...<commit2>` which is useful for
>    merges. The resulting set of commits is the symmetric difference
>    between the two operands. ...

which I suspect is confusing enough wording (and actually `git diff` uses a quite different meaning).  But really, it's not that complicated.

Given some commits that could be drawn like this:

```
master  origin/master

   E       G
   |       |
   D       F
     \   /
       C
       |
       B
       |
       A
```

what you have is a divergence at commit `C`.  You started work when `master` and `origin/master` both pointed to `C`.  Clearly, you committed `D` and `E`, and "they" (whoever they are) committed `F` and `G`.  Commit `C`, by the way, is called the *merge base*.

What `master...origin/master` means is: find me `C`, and then give me everything "up from there", on both the left and right sides.  That is, all the commits on both `master` *and* `origin/master`, excluding any commits at-and-below the point where they first meet.

If you run `gitk master...origin/master` you'll see just that:<sup>2</sup> all the commits *you* made, and all the commits *they* made.  But, if you run `git diff flags master...origin/master`, `git diff` throws most of this out.  Instead, it finds the merge base `C`,<sup>3</sup> and diffs that against the right-hand side name.

Assuming you're on your `master` branch (i.e., `HEAD` simply means "master" anyway), you can shorten this even further.  To see what files they modified since your and their branches diverged, just run:

```
$ git diff --stat ...origin/master   # or --name-status, etc
```

Leaving the name out means `HEAD`, so this is the same as `HEAD...origin/master` which is the same as `master...origin/master`.

If your git is new enough, `@{u}` refers to "the current branch's upstream branch" (i.e., from `master`, find `origin/master`), so you can run:

```
$ git diff --stat '...@{u}'
```

(the quotes are to protect the braces from the shell; they may or may not be needed in your particular shell).  This works even if you're on `develop` with `origin/develop` as its upstream, or `featureX` with `origin/featureX` as its upstream, etc.

---

<sup>1</sup>If you don't have `gitk`, try:

```
$ git log --graph --boundary ...origin/master
```

(or `'...@{u}'` as noted above). You need the `--boundary` to include the merge commit.  You might want to add `--oneline --decorate` as well.

<sup>2</sup>Actually `gitk` will show you the merge commit too, just like the command in footnote 1.  That is, it uses `--boundary` to include meeting-point commits (this is not quite the same as merge bases, but close enough).

<sup>3</sup>This assumes there is exactly one merge base commit.  For these cases, that should be true.  So, `git diff` compares the tree for `C` with the tree for `G` at the head of the upstream branch.  You'll compare "where they were" with "where they ended up", regardless of any intermediate points they visited on perhaps an arbitrarily long drive. :-)  For instance, if commit `F` adds a file `this/that` and then commit `G` removes it again, you won't see the file.

Answer (score 3):

```
git diff --stat master origin/master
```

Comment: This actually compares your current commit (`master`) against theirs (`origin/master`), which is not *quite* the same thing.